# javax.servlet cannot be resolved fo OpenShift Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jboss, openshift

I was building the first project for OpenShift the PaaS.  Decided to go with java so downloaded the JBoss Developer Studio and created the first poject.  Openshift kind of already created the template so it should run.  But in the developer studio, there is error:

> javax.servlet cannot be resolved

I know this could be simple for Java EE people but my question is that for OpenShift, would the solution be same.  Can we just copy an apache tomcat jar to the project folder?  JBoss Develper Studio is not exactly Eclipse I guess?  So I added the jar and the error disappeared.  Then there is this warning:

> Classpath entry .. tomecat-7.0.42/lib/servlet-api.jar will not be
>   exported or published  ClassNotFoundException may result.

**Question**

What is the right thing for the error and warning to disappear?  Should Openshift already have the jar since it's a PaaS, not IaaS.  Do we just need the jar to build but this jar will not be part of the web app?

**Info**

The JBoss Developer Studio does have pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>tom</groupId>
    <artifactId>tom</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>tom</name>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eap</id>
            <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>eap</id>
            <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
        </dependency>           
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
                invoking mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
                will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'webapps' 
                folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>tom</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: yeah... copying random `jar`s around is probably a bad idea. A `jar` is a compressed collection of `class` files.

Comment: looks like he used external jars, otherwise, why the warning is pointing to another path?  A newbie might have tried different things and forgot what finally made it to work.  Normally the servlet-api.jar (tomcat) is part of the JBOSS server already.  For developer, one just need to have it to compile.

Comment: are you using maven? if yes please show your pom.xml

Comment: @fascynacja I have added the pom.xml although I don't know much about maven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the default pom.xml doesn't have the correct dependency for servlet-api.  Following the guide in this page and you may find it working

https://www.openshift.com/blogs/multipart-forms-and-file-uploads-with-tomcat-7

Answer (score 6):

The artifactId differs from what is typically used to reference the dependency on mavenCentral.
For OpenShift's repo use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```